# Django 1.9: MySQLdb does not exist - python 3.5

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am running python 3.5 on windows 10 64bit with django installed with pip.

For some reason MySQL will not work. (It is running off of an Xampp server on port 3306) Please help!

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': 'dbs.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

dbs.cnf

```
[client]
database = test
host = 127.0.0.1
user = server
password = secretPassword
default-character-set = utf8
```

Command:

```
C:\Users\...\backend>python manage.py makemigrations user_database
```

stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Comment: Have you installed the mysqlclient with `pip install mysqlclient`?

Comment: I get this: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: There seem to be issues installing `mysqlclient` with Python 3.5 using pip on Windows. You might find it easier to use Python 3.4 instead. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/54) for more details.